# Clarification on singular points of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Given a certain integral.

How to distinguish the singular points. 
I already familiar with the point that turn the denominator to zero.

Are there more conditions for distinguishing singular points?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @AnyAD Singular point is when the integral supposedly is tending to infinity